# bot.get_all_members() возвращает Member самого бота

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Почему-то метод get_all_members() стал возвращать только бота. Возможно произошли некоторые изменения в Discord API, может я чего-то не знаю? Вот сам фрагмент кода:

```
for g in bot.get_all_members():
   print(g)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `get_all_members` возвращает участников только из кэша.

Для полного заполнения кэша с начала работы бота, боту необходимо получать их из gateway при помощи intent `members` либо через ручной запрос, который может занять намного больше времени, нежели получение данных с gateway.

На скриншоте первая половина - с members intent, вторая - без

[image: members=True: 11052 пользователей в bot.users, members=False: 2 пользователя в bot.users]

[Подробнее про intents в документации библиотеки](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

В Вашем случае, Вам скорее всего нужно просто включить необходимый intent в панели управления бота со стороны дискорда и добавить объект с необходимыми intents как аргумент в конструктор бота. (`bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=discord.Intents.all())` например)

Comment: да, спасибо, в этом и была проблема. А что такое intents?

Comment: "Списки" событий, на которые "подписывается" ваш бот: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents